# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

In my code I understand query getting null values and it throws this error. But since my query is little complex I don't understand how do I check for null values and avoid this error. Please help me to correct this query.

```
SELECT (SUM(charges) + SUM(behaviour) + SUM(admission) + SUM(properInformation) + SUM(hygine) + SUM(treatment))/(count(doctorID) * 6) AverageRating, COUNT(ID) RatingCount from ratings where doctorID = '" + doctorID + "'
```

Comment: Your error does not sound like it is the query itself. Sounds like you are not declaring something in your code as new.

Comment: The error is a .NET error, not an SQL error. Of course it may be caused by the result of your select, but you'll need to give us more details about the code to get help on that part.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Updated my code. Please have a look.

Comment: What line specifically are you getting this error?

Comment: Can't tell for sure what blows up, however you'll always get one row back for a sum, however if the doctor does not exist you'll get dbnull/null back as averagerating which may cause trouble.

Comment: you can find a good answer for your question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/26761773#26761773

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Ok. I got the error. But I am changing my post please concern that what is actual problem

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson My actual problem is Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Double' is not valid. Please solve this in my query. And sorry for wrong post earlier..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the query to not return `NULL`, you can just surround the expression with `IFNULL` to convert a possible NULL to 0, something like;

```
SELECT IFNULL((SUM(charges) + SUM(behaviour) + SUM(admission) + 
               SUM(properInformation) + SUM(hygine) + SUM(treatment))
              /(count(doctorID) * 6), 0) AverageRating, 
       COUNT(ID) RatingCount 
FROM ratings 
WHERE doctorID = '" + doctorID + "'
```

Comment: Will this only convert a null sum to 0, or convert any nulls in any of the summed columns to 0?

Comment: @AaronD Just the null sum, if you want the individual sums turned to 0 you need an ifnull around each sum. SQL isn't very flexible when it comes to adding a null with any other value, sadly.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's what I expected. It would have been nice though, heh.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely know your query returning null value correctly, then you can use try-catch block as below:

```
Try
Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT (SUM(charges) + SUM(behaviour) + SUM(admission) + SUM(properInformation)
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Error while fetching data" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
End Try
```